# Outlook HTML signature with external text

Tags: html, outlook, signature, outlook-2010

The company I work for has implemented new signatures to be used with Outlook 2010. Our company is also present at many exhibitions a year, and we would like to let our clients know just that.

The problem is that I want to load an external text file in our html signatures, so that I only need to update one file that contains the information on the exhibitions we'll be attending.

Outlook strips iframe tags, object tags and it seems I am unable to run php scripts as well.

Can anyone help me find an alternative?

Comment: I think this might belong on SuperUser. What you are trying to do is possible though, I think.

Comment: http://email.about.com/od/outlookexpresstips/ss/wt120603.htm - try this.

Comment: I think you'll be able to keep that HTML file updated externally, maybe through a Scheduled Task that runs a PHP script.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, i can't get it to work. Any kind of scripting is disabled in Outlook, as we all want it, but that also makes my idea impossible to implement. I guess I should take the manual approach.

Answer (score 0):

Write an outlook plugin to search signatures for a special moniker and replace it with the desired text coming from a company accessible location (e.g. intranet, ActiveDirectory, website, etc).

Outlook stores signatures C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures so you can retrieve this folder with something to the tune of

```
string SignaturePath = Path.Combine(
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Microsoft", "Signatures));
```

From here, I would use FileIO to iterate through the signatures, and append my desired text.  If you're working within a large enterprise, the outlook VTSO files can be configured to be pushed down using your company's centralized software update/installer software.